# php constant gets duplicated inside foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, constants

I've been strugling with this problem for some time now. I can't figure out whats wrong.
Following code is very simple, VISOR_URL is a constant defined in another file. If i echo it outside forearch loop it prints the constant value. If I print it inside the loop it's value gets duplicated. 
Same problem occurs if I use a variable.
Any ideas?.
Thanks in advance.
Sebastian

```
<?php
require_once('conf.php');//I require the file where VISOR_URL is defined
//VISOR_URL is defined in conf.php. define('VISOR_URL', $server_ip.'/'.VISOR_NAME);

echo VISOR_URL; //echoes http://192.168.0.15/tncvisornuevo

if (!empty($occurrence_ids)) {//occurrence_ids is an array and values are printed fine

    foreach ($occurrence_ids as $key => $value) {
        echo VISOR_URL; //echoes http://192.168.0.15/tncvisornuevohttp://192.168.0.15/tncvisornuevo 

        $ocurrencia = new ca_occurrences($value);

        $nombre_ocurrencia = $ocurrencia->get('ca_occurrences.preferred_labels');

        $link = '<a href="'.VISOR_URL.'/views/occurrenceDetails.php?occurrence_id='.$value.'">'.$nombre_ocurrencia.'</a>';

        echo $link."<br>";
    }

}
?>
```

Following simple example does not duplicate the constant value:

```
<?php

//Define a constant
define('CONSTANT', 'imaconstant');

echo CONSTANT."<br>"; //Echoes imaconstant

$test_array = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);

foreach ($test_array as $key => $value) {
    echo $value.CONSTANT,"<br>"; //Echoes nimaconstant, n+1imaconstant

}

?>
```

Comment: Check that `new ca_occurrences($value);` or `$ocurrencia->get` is not outputting the value of `VISOR_URL`.

Answer (score 1):

It'll echo it as many times the loop will run. For example -

```
$array = array('aa','bb','cc');
$var = "abc";

foreach($array as $key => $value);
{
    echo $var.'<br>';
}

/*   
   abc
   abc
   abc
*/
```

Now above since the array has size of 3, the loop will run 3 times and echoes the variable...ofcourse 3 times.

Comment: OP echos other things in the loop though. `echo VISOR_URL; ...; echo $link."<br>";`

Comment: And if I want to use $var inside  the foreach loop?

Comment: @sms - I'm printing `$var` inside `foreach` only

Comment: Yes that's the behavior I expect. But in my first code example it prints abcabc in every loop.